# Copy names from one sheet into another sheet based off date selected

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I've created a workbook to track ticket sales for an event we have coming up. The guests have the choice of Thu, Fri, or Sun.

I'd like to pull the names form the list where the days are selected and put them into a list on a different sheets that correspond to the date selected.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: besides `VLOOKUP`, which is already suggested, you can use pivot tables and macros too.

Comment: I kind of figured that, but I'm not sure how to get any of those things to work together to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: OK I got Vlookup to work, however, it just keeps grabbing the same name over and over again. How do I get it not to repeat itself.

Comment: then please share what you have already tried and explain why those don't  work. Otherwise there's a high chance we'll suggest what you've already tried.

Comment: OK,

Here's my formula: =VLOOKUP("Thu",'Ticket Sales'!A:B,2,0)

On the Ticket Sales sheet, you can select "Thu" "Fri" or "Sun"

When I copy the above formula into other cells, I just keep getting the first name on the list that has Thu selected. How do I make it ignore a name once it has pulled it?

Comment: Maybe Vlookup is the wrong way to go. I don't have a lot of experience with excel and I don't know how to write macros.

Answer (score -1):

You can!  Here is a fab video on doing a [vlookup](http://www.google.com/urlhttp://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&rct=j&q=vlookup%20in%20excel%20&ved=0CCIQuAIwAmoVChMI7rLCmdDfyAIVBuwmCh0EbQvX&url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D-WAEzokHSJM&usg=AFQjCNEbdJ7eN7GwWJLlITa9TgGqaCukog&sig2=qYNljN_ho0bMCkVNlb3Wxg). It's a function in Excel that is excellent at checking a value in a range. Enjoy.

Comment: link only answers are discouraged in superuser, please see our help to learn how to write a good answer: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer